# Imports just on API level > 15

Tags: android

I have a App created on API 8. Now I want to make it work with ICS and for that I need additional imports which are not available in API 8. 
I want to add following imports:

```
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
```

So do I have to make a diffenent app just for API > 15? The name of the App should not change.

Or maybe it is possible to place 2 App versions and make the minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion according to the API level into Google Play?

How do you handle that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a App created on API 8.

Great!

> Now I want to make it work with ICS and for that I need additional imports which are not available in API 8.

No problem! Since `import` statements are applied at compile time, so long as you set your project's build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android) to API Level 14 or higher, your code will compile fine.

> So do I have to make a diffenent app just for API > 15?

No. Just use version guard blocks to ensure that you do not try using the newer code on older devices:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
  // do stuff with CalendarContract
}
```

> Or maybe it is possible to place 2 App versions and make the minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion according to the API level into Google Play?

That should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a compatibility shim to your existing app so that it works on lower API levels and is still able to access API's from higher levels.

In general, the way to do this is to isolate the code that uses the higher-level API's in classes that are loaded at run-time via reflection, only if the API level supports them.